# Как задать стили для ОДНОМУ из элементов с одним классом?

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-selectors

```
<h3 class="advantage-title">Настоящий городок</h3>
<h3 class="advantage-title">Близкий поселок</h3>
<h3 class="advantage-title">Стальной замок</h3>
<h3 class="advantage-title">Красивая кухня</h3>
<h3 class="advantage-title">Просторная прихожая</h3>
```

Нужно задать стили только для третьего элемента сверху (Стальной замок). Как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Например так

```
.advantage-title:nth-child(3n) {
  color: red
}
```